# How to add “enter” option to p:dataTable globalFilter

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using **primefaces 3.2**

Currently the `globalFilter` in `dataTable` is activate when the user right character.
Instead this functionality I want to add an `onclick=”enter”` option meaning the user can add a string but the search option will be activate only by pressing `enter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen & respond to *Enter* key code only,

So replace

```
<p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />
```

With

```
<p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {carsTable.filter()}" style="width:150px" />
```

`event.keyCode == 13` ---> enter is pressed